# ThreeJS font not loading

Tags: fonts, three.js

i recently started working with ThreeJS and i can't figure this out .
i wanted to load my own fonts to display a 3D Text object in the scene , i followed along [this example](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_shadowmap.html) and everything went well , but now when i only change the "font: " option in TextGeometry Object , everything fells apart and nothing is displayed ( Error is that the font is undefined )

i use typeFace to create the fonts and including the script seems to be fine , 
i personally thing that there is something with the font's name that i'm typing it wrong , because i read somewhere that everything between .typeface.js is the actual font name that threeJS is looking for and should be included ( in lowercase ) , but in the example , there's no _regular . 
or maybe the difference between font-name and font-family ... don't know !

thanks .

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="mrdoob-three.js-1769fbf/examples/fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="trebuchet_ms.typeface.js"></script>


        var textGeo = new THREE.TextGeometry( "THREE.JS", {
            size: 50,
            height: 10,
            curveSegments: 50,
    //        font: "helvetiker",  works fine 
            font: "trebuchet_ms",
    //        weight: "bold",
    //        style: "normal",
            bevelThickness: 11,
            bevelSize: 0,
            bevelEnabled: true
        });
        textGeo.computeBoundingBox();
        var textMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xff0000} );
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( textGeo, textMaterial );
        mesh.position.set(0,0,0) ;
        mesh.castShadow = true;
        mesh.receiveShadow = true;
        scene.add( mesh );
```

> Uncaught The font trebuchet with normal weight and normal style is
>   missing.

Comment: How did you create this font?

Comment: using http://typeface.neocracy.org/fonts.html

Comment: remove the underscore from the font name or better yet name the font file `trebuchet_regular`.

Comment: How is the font named in the typeface.js file? Can you try it with a font that does not have underscores?

Comment: "full_font_name":"Trebuchet MS","font_family_name":"Trebuchet MS" ,i'll try them in a sec ;)

Comment: For future reference, since http://typeface.neocracy.org/fonts.html is down, use http://gero3.github.io/facetype.js/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is how to find the font name to use:

1. Open up the typeface.js file
2. Look for the font_family property: `"font_family_name":"Trebuchet MS"`
3. Change it to *all lowercase*. Spaces are fine.

So in your particular example:

```
var textGeo = new THREE.TextGeometry( "THREE.JS", {

    size: 200,
    height: 50,
    curveSegments: 12,

    font: "trebuchet ms",
    // weight: "normal",
    // style: "normal",

    bevelThickness: 2,
    bevelSize: 5,
    bevelEnabled: true

});
```

Tip: When in doubt, evaluate `THREE.FontUtils.faces` in the browser console when you hit the error. This will give you the names of all the currently registered fonts.

Comment: You don't have to adjust the font name in the typeface, Just *reference* it in lowercase:  `new THREE.TextGeometry(str, {font: "trebuchet ms"})`

Comment: Thanks for the tip on THREE.FontUtils.faces.